# Proof : Limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Prove from the definition of the limit of a sequence that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n^2+\cos(n)} {n^2+1} = 2 $$
>
> (that is, for a given $\epsilon > 0$, find an explicit $N_\epsilon$)

Please explain.

I choose $n_0$ such that ${n_0} > \sqrt {\frac{3}{\varepsilon }} $. Then how can I say that for all $n\ge n_0$, we have $\left| {\frac{{2{n^2} + \cos n}}
{{{n^2} + 1}} - 2} \right| <\varepsilon$. ? How to proceed further ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Choose an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_0 > \sqrt{\frac 1{\epsilon}}$. Then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \ge n_0$, we have
\begin{align}
\left| {\frac{{2{n^2} + \cos n}}
{{{n^2} + 1}} -2 } \right|&=\left| {\frac{{2{n^2} + \cos n}}
{{{n^2} + 1}} - \frac{2(n^2+1)}{n^2+1}} \right|\\ &=\left|\frac{\cos n -2}{n^2+1} \right| \\
&=\left|\frac{\cos n}{n^2+1}-\frac 2{n^2+1} \right| \\
&\le\left|\frac{\cos n}{n^2+1} \right|+\left|\frac 2{n^2+1} \right| \\
&=\frac{|\cos n|}{n^2+1}+\frac 2{n^2+1} \\
&\le \frac 1{n^2+1}+\frac 2{n^2+1} \\
&=\frac 3{n^2+1} \\
&< \frac 3{n^2} \\
&\le \frac 3{n_0^2} \\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}

Comment: I already done this work that yo did. I am not able to proceed further with this

Comment: I choose $n_0$ such that ${n_0} > \sqrt {\frac{3}{\varepsilon }} $.

Comment: It's simpler if you go one step further and do $\frac{3}{n^2+1} < \frac{3}{n^2}$.

Comment: what after that. what am I suppose to do after that ?

Comment: @JamesMatthew marty cohen suggested working with $\frac 3{n_0^2}<\epsilon$ instead. This is much better than my original suggestion of working with $\frac 3{n_0^2+1}<\epsilon$. In fact, $\frac 3{n_0^2}<\epsilon$ will give you $n_0 > \sqrt{\frac 3{\epsilon}}$, as you had chosen precisely in the first place.

Comment: @JamesMatthew What you are left to do now is write a formal proof. I modified the answer accordingly to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\left | \frac{2n^{2}+\cos(n)}{n^{2}+1}-2 \right |=\frac{\left | -2+\cos(n) \right |}{n^{2}+1}\leq\frac{3}{n^{2}+1}<\epsilon.$$